# android jackson json object mapper array deserialization

Tags: android, json, jackson, pojo

i need help parsing a response with the jackson mapper to a POJO. i have this as a response:

```
 "data": [{
        "item": {
            "downloaded": false,
            "moderated": false,
            "add": false
        }
    },
    {
        "item": {
            "downloaded": false,
            "moderated": false,
            "add": false }
// more
```

so how do i bind this one with the mapper to a POJO?
here is my class that i am trying but it returns that "item" is not recognized and not allowed to be ignored.

```
public ArrayList<Item> data =  new ArrayList<Item>();
```

where item is a public static class Item with constructors and all the fields above with getters and setters.

how do i do this. i cant seem to find anywhere how to read data from an array this way.

Comment: JSON structure looks quite redundant: why are there 'item' entries there? Is this converted from XML or something? Also: please include definition of Item class (or indicate that you'd like it to be defined too)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your example is missing couple of pieces (esp. definition of Item), to know if your structure is compatible; but in general JSON and Object structures need to match. So, you would at least need something like:

```
public class DataWrapper {
  public List<Item> data; // or if you prefer, setters+getters
}
```

and if so, you would bind with:

```
DataWrapper wrapper = mapper.readValue(json, DataWrapper.class);
```

and access data as

```
List<Item> items = wrapper.data;
```

Answer (score 12):

```
JsonNode jsonNode = mapper.readValue(s, JsonNode.class); 
JsonNode userCards = jsonNode.path("data");
List<Item> list = mapper.readValue(userCards.toString(), new TypeReference<List<Item>>(){});
```

Comment: This answer would be much better if you included some text with it to explain *how* and *why* it addresses the issue.

Comment: I found this approach preferable to that by StaxMan.  Reason being is that StaxMan's requires an extra object to wrap the array/list.  This approach only requires an extra line.  I rewrote my code slightly differently from maziar's, eliminates an extra line.  See my answer, though it's just a variant of maziar's.

Comment: @awoodland : someone can probably explain better than me; but, in simple terms, the problem is that the OP's JSON isn't a single object of type Item, it's an array/list of Items.  You've got to tell Jackson to expect a list, not an object.  See my answer below, which is simpler, and it might make more sense to you.  Converting to a JsonNode first works, but seems superfluous (AFAIK).  I could be wrong though, maybe something is missing in the output.  Seems to work for me though.

Answer (score 2):

Here's my variant of maziar's code.

```
List<Item> list = mapper.readValue( s, new TypeReference<List<Item>>(){} );
```

It just eliminates the converting first to a JsonNode and converts instead directly to a List; still works fine, outputting a list of Items.